# How to construct nested lists in rust-polars?

Tags: rust-polars

I tried having an outer and an inner `ListPrimitiveChunkedBuilder` where I'd append the inner to the outer but I'd get warnings that the types don't match.

I found a work around of making a df, turning it lazy, imploding, then concating like this:

```
let mut coords: ListPrimitiveChunkedBuilder<Float64Type> = 
    ListPrimitiveChunkedBuilder::new(
    "coordinates", 2, 2, DataType::Float64);
coords.append_slice(&[1.1,2.2]);
coords.append_slice(&[2.1,2.32]);
let cos = coords.finish().into_series();
let sa = cos.cast(&DataType::Array(Box::new(DataType::Float64), 2)).unwrap();

let df = DataFrame::new(vec![sa]).unwrap();
let lf = df.lazy();
let df = lf.select([col("coordinates").implode()]).collect().expect("err");

let mut coords: ListPrimitiveChunkedBuilder<Float64Type> = ListPrimitiveChunkedBuilder::new(
    "coordinates", 1, 2, DataType::Float64);

coords.append_slice(&[3.1,12.2]);
coords.append_slice(&[4.1,12.32]);
let cos = coords.finish().into_series();
let sa = cos.cast(&DataType::Array(Box::new(DataType::Float64), 2)).unwrap();

let df2 = DataFrame::new(vec![sa]).unwrap();
let lf2: LazyFrame = df2.lazy();
let df2: DataFrame = lf2.select([col("coordinates").implode()]).collect().expect("err");


let df3 = concat_df([&df, &df2]).unwrap();
println!("{:?}",df3)
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────┐
│ coordinates                 │
│ ---                         │
│ list[array[f64, 2]]         │
╞═════════════════════════════╡
│ [[1.1, 2.2], [2.1, 2.32]]   │
│ [[3.1, 12.2], [4.1, 12.32]] │
└─────────────────────────────┘
```

I'm sure there's a more straightforward way to do it but I couldn't find it as of yet..